# Can questions asking for list of list on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

<sub>(The title is clumsy. I appreciate any help on making it better.)</sub>

The question I'm about to ask may be classified as a recommendation question, therefore it may be closed. However, since it can be worded as "looking for a research", which can be a literary analysis question, and I'm not sure if it would be on-topic again.

Here is my draft:

> I'm having a research about a psychological disorder named Borderline Personality Disorder, and my goal is to introduce information about BPD to people with literature/art background. Do you know any authors/books/characters that can be a good introduction for BPD? It needs not to be an exact diagnosis from qualified therapists, but just popular enough and have some BPD traits.
>
> If you need to summarize the disorder in three words, here it is: **fear of abandonment**. Here is the lists of all BPD traits (taken from [Borderline personality disorder | NAMI: National Alliance on Mental Illness](https://www.nami.org/learn-more/mental-health-conditions/borderline-personality-disorder)):
>
> > People with BPD experience wide mood swings and can feel a great sense of instability and insecurity. According to the Diagnostic and Statistical Manual diagnostic framework, some key signs and symptoms may include:
> >
> > [List of symptoms]
>
> You can also watch a short clip about this: https://youtu.be/BFop1UxiDdY

The question can be asked under this wording: **is there any research about literature works that can depict BPD?**